# What`s the VARNISHSRC path for Varnish installations on ubuntu via apt-get?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, varnish

I'm building a docker container with Varnish 3.0 and I need to compile [libvmod-cookie](https://github.com/varnish/libvmod-cookie).
The docker container uses `ubuntu:14.04.2` as image.

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04.2

RUN apt-get update -qq && \
  apt-get upgrade -yqq && \
  apt-get -yqq install make curl build-essential git automake \
    pkg-config libmhash-dev python-docutils sed libtool libpcre3 libpcre3-dev \
    libreadline6-dev libeditline0 libeditline-dev psmisc net-tools \
  libvarnishapi-dev automake autotools-dev libedit-dev libjemalloc-dev \
  libncurses-dev libpcre3-dev libtool pkg-config python-docutils python-sphinx \
  graphviz varnish && \
  apt-get -yqq clean

RUN git clone https://github.com/varnish/libvmod-cookie.git && cd libvmod-cookie \
  && git checkout libvmod-cookie-1.01 && ./autogen.sh &&  \
  ./configure && make && make install    

EXPOSE 80

CMD ["/var/www/yazawa/install.sh"]
```

As you can see in my Dockerfile I'm doing the following steps to build libvmod-cookie:

```
sudo apt-get install varnish
./autogen.sh
./configure
make
make install
```

But I got an error message:

```
...    
configure: error: No Varnish source tree specified
```

I think I have to set VARNISHSRC path with the `./configure`...

```
./configure VARNISHRC=/path/to/varnish
```

But I don't know the path of Varnish source tree when installed via apt-get.
Is this the right way? Or am I completelly lost?